# CSS is causing SQL INSERT to execute twice

Tags: php, html, css, phpmyadmin

I have an `INSERT` query in my `PHP` page which executes once as it is supposed to, and works fine, just how I want.

```
if(!$con->query("INSERT INTO contracts (CID, DATE, NUMBER, TITLE, DESCRIPTION) VALUES ('$cid', '" . $con->real_escape_string($date) . "', '" . $con->real_escape_string($number[$counter]) . "', '" . $con->real_escape_string($title[$counter]) . "', '" . $con->real_escape_string($description[$counter]) . "')"))
            {
                printf("Error message: %s\n", $con->error);
            }
```

Now, I add the following `CSS` in the same `PHP` file to make a table I output a bit nicer to read:

```
<style>
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: e5e4e2;
}
</style>
```

That makes every other row a grey colour, great... but wait! Now my `SQL` `INSERT` happens twice. I have no idea how these are connected, when I remove the `CSS`, the INSERT executes once like I need.
Is there some jiggery pokery I am not understanding here? **How can `CSS` possibly affect my `SQL` query?**
For the record I am using **XAMPP**, **PHP version 5.5.15** and **phpMyAdmin** for the database tables.
**EDIT**: I have checked the database, it is inserting twice. 
 The query is set to a button and I use `if (isset($_GET['insertIt'])) {// INSERT QUERY` so that when the user clicks this button:
 `<a href = 'testing.php?insertIt=true'><button style="height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px">2. Insert New Contracts To 'contracts' Table</button></a>`
The query is sent. It works fine without the `CSS`, but with, it runs twice
**EDIT 2:** OK, here are the two screenshots from Developer tools when I click the button. I found that it's not the omission of the `CSS` exactly but the `<style> ... </style>` tags; when I leave those out I get this:[image] 
When they are in my `PHP` file I get this:[image] 
I can accept this and try to get around it by separating the files or leaving the tags out completely but I would still love to know **why it happens.** I am no expert but I can see there is an extra call to `insertIt` when there are no `<style>` tags and the entries are inserted twice.
For the record I want to be able to

1. click the button
2. insert the entries once
3. and refresh the page as the page also displays the results of the insert.

Comment: What event triggers the INSERT ?

Comment: everything looks correct and it can't do entry twice. might some other part of code is doing this

Comment: Post more code,as it is I doubt the problem is the CSS

Comment: "CSS is causing SQL INSERT to execute" is absolutly not in anyway, event slightly possible

Comment: @Mihai the problem isn't in the css but how he add the css to the php page.

Comment: try to decouple the css and the php file.

Comment: How can you tell it is executing twice? Did you check it directly in the database?

Comment: @atmd Of course it's possible - check runtime styles for grey `tr`s, and for each one kick off ajax to insert data. Saying that, I'm somewhat dubious phpmyadmin actually works in that way.

Comment: i guess, but you'd need 'something' to check the styles and trigger some sort of server action. so I'd say that that 'something' i.e. javascript can do it, but not css directly.

Comment: Maybe one day #someElement{ databaseInsert : "Values() INTO()"} will be a reality. we can dream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code snippets isn't enough of course, but let me suggest you the solution and explain a bit of what you doing here.

1. Using GET in this case isn't good enough. I don't know what are you doing next (any redirect after record is inserted?), but I suppose that nothing is happening. A good idea would be to use POST, cause you creating the row in the table.
2. The action which triggers the form is a click, but the click on what? You have a button inside a link. `<a><button></button></a>` not elements are control elements. I would suggest fix it to `<button type="submit" style="height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px">2. Insert New Contracts To 'contracts' Table</button>`  and get rid of `<a>`, the URL you will post to should come from form action attribute. If you really need to post with an event using JavaScript, this is another story, code you provided isn't enough to see what are you trying to achieve.
3. When someone may argue that redirect after record creation is bad due to HTTP protocol standards, but this is a common practice to redirect to the same page after performing actions with form, to prevent multiple records creation by accidentally refreshing the page.

Here goes pseudocode of what I think you should do:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["...field name..."])) {
       ... perform INSERT ...
       ... do redirect to 'testing.php' ...
    } 
?>

<form action="testing.php" method="post">
    ... fields ...
   <button type="submit" style="height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px">2. Insert New Contracts To 'contracts' Table</button>
</form>
```

Nothing should happen twice. If you need more help - be my guest and ask.

Comment: I accepted this as it helped me accomplish my task and gives good advice. I used POST with PRG to avoid resubmission issues. The problem I had was fixed by separating PHP and CSS files. However, I am still wondering why the <style> tags caused my query to execute twice.

Comment: would be nice to see all the code, to try to reproduce, hard to answer right now. the issue must be somewhere else, not in the <style> tag. could you post it here?